# How can the formless assume a form(incarnation)?

Tags: advaita

God is formless and he assumes a form, say.
Then that body is bound by time, space and causation. And anything bound has to change. But god is constant. Then are incarnations true? Then where are all the incarnations so claimed? Can an idol be called god?

Also how can god be with and without form?  The idea that he is both with and without form is false. Because when the form dies a part of god dies. But god has no part, he is whole, changeless.

Comment: Does water have any specific shape? No. It takes the shape of the container that contains it, similarly a formless we call god takes the form of the body during incarnations. It is defined as "a person who embodies in the flesh a deity, spirit, or abstract quality."

Comment: From Gospel of Ramakrishna: "Think of Brahman, Existence-Knowledge- Bliss Absolute, as a shoreless ocean. Through the cooling influence, as it were, of the bhakta's love, the water has frozen at places into blocks of ice. In other words, God now and then assumes various forms for His lovers and reveals Himself to them as a Person. But with the rising of the sun of Knowledge, the blocks of ice melt. Then one doesn't feel any more that God is a Person, nor does one see God's forms. What He is cannot be described." http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/06_brahmo_devotees_i.htm

Comment: God doesnt take birth in the body made of five elements of nature. That's why it is known as avatar.

Comment: Since Brahman's assumed physical form is made from the 5 great elements, a product of prakriti, it must again return back to those 5 elements. Nirguna brahman, is no doubt eternal & changeless, but upon union with prakriti, it assumes a temporal body of flesh and bones. He simply chooses a vessel or clothing (flesh body) to interact with other flesh bodies (imparting knowledge to the pious, killing the wicked etc.) After his work is done, he gives up his vessel or clothing and returns to nirguna state  ... It's his clothing of flesh which dies. Not him as the divine spirit Brahman.

Comment: But how exactly the union takes place, that brings forth all incarnations is not even known to me. Someone well versed in the scriptures can explain that procedure here. Or maybe it's not to be found in any scriptures but only in the philosophy of samkhya. Anyway, if someone is familiar with the gradual creationary process , can share it here.